# How to control the window title position with Infragistics Ribbon when contextual tabs displayed

Tags: winforms, ribbon, infragistics

[image: Ribbon]

Does anyone know which settings control the position of the Windows title i.e. the "Office 2010 Style Ribbon with Applica..." shown here? In the sample the title moves relative to the contextual tab depending on the space available. So if you shrink the window it will jump to the left of the tab.

In my application this does not happen. The title stubbornly stay to the right even if there is very little room. I guess we have set something that is controlling this but I can't find-out what this could be, anyone know how this is controlled?

Comment: Do you have a sample that shows the behavior?  Have you asked Infragistics support through either the forums or a support case?

Comment: No, unfortunately it only manifests in our full product. Yes I have asked Infragistics, they have yet to provide anything useful.

Comment: Do you have a case number or a forum post link that I could look at?